# JavaScript: How do I sort times in a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, time

I'm working with a JSON file that contains the 2021 NFL schedule. I'm able to easily filter out Thursday, Sunday & Monday games. The filtering method returns my Sunday games in an array of objects.

Below is a look at how my Sunday array is set up. This code just shows the first two weeks for the Packers, but there are 18 weeks in the schedule, and I have the same info for each team.

So for the first week, for example, I'll have an array of 14 games. (The 14 teams are the visiting teams.) I need to loop through the games for the desired week and sort the array by the time of the games. A typical Sunday will have games at 12:00 PM, 3:25 PM, and 7:15 PM. There are other starting times throughout the season.

```
[
    {
      "name": "Green Bay Packers",
      "id": 1,
      "nickname": "Packers",
      "homefield": "Lambeau Field",
      "division": "NFC North",
      "schedule": [
        {
          "week": "1",
          "date": "Sept. 12",
          "weekday": "Sunday",
          "time": "3:25 PM",
          "network": "Fox",
          "opponent": "New Orleans Saints",
          "homeAway": "away",
          "venue": "Mercedes-Benz Superdome"
        },
        {
          "week": "2",
          "date": "Sept. 19",
          "weekday": "Monday",
          "time": "7:15 PM",
          "network": "ESPN",
          "opponent": "Detroit Lions",
          "homeAway": "home",
          "venue": "Lambeau Field"
        },
    etc.
```

Comment: what have you tried so far and can you paste it here.

Comment: can your backend provide a better data format like `2021-09-19` as one additional property? If so, would be easy to sort the array. Look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/mathiasgheno/4a70dd9c3835b6ce4b072194f0e31986

Comment: @vaira I haven't tried anything because I'm totally stuck.  I've seen code to sort times, but I can't figure out how to do this with a nested array.

Comment: @Mathias Gheno Azzolini I made the JSON file, so I can add anything to it, but that gist seems to be sorting dates, not times.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  "su" is my array of Sunday games, so I pass that and the week number into my function.

```
function sortSundayByTime(su, weekNo) {
  su.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.schedule[weekNo].time < b.schedule[weekNo].time) {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.schedule[weekNo].time > b.schedule[weekNo].time) {
      return 1;
    }
  });
}
```